# How do I navigate from a dialog button to the code behind?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

Cant believe I cant figure out how to do this.
If im looking at a created dialog in the dev studio and it has an ok button, how do I quickly get to the code for when the OK button is clicked?

At the moment I have to copy the resource ID for the dialog e.g. 'IDD_MYDIALOG'
search for that in the source files, open the source file, then start looking for an On_Ok() style function then do a search on that function then open it.

Thanks

ps Id also like to know how to do the same for menu selections.

Comment: What about making a doubleclick on that button? At least in WinForm and WPF You are redirected to the Click-EventHandler-method. Or when You mark the button on the form, You can see a window with the properties of that button. Select then the events and You can doubleclick the cell containing the name of the eventhandle. Then You are redirected too.

Comment: To be honest thats what I was expecting to do but neither works.  This is in Visual studio 2012

Comment: Navigation support is built into the [MFC Class Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748520(v=vs.110).aspx). If you right-click on a button, and select *Class Wizard...* it opens the dialog with the respective entries, allowing you to *Add Handler...* or *Edit Code*, for example. The latter allows you to jump to the implementation.

Comment: I've never done anything using the Wizard! Every time I need, I add the `OnOK()` method declaration on the `.h` file and its implementation on the `.cpp` file all by hand!